# Word which means "in its early stages but important"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I came across a word a while ago which I had to look that had the definition along the lines of "in its early stages but important / powerful / poignant" and I can't for the life of me remember what it was...

Anyone any ideas, it's driving me a bit mad! :D

Comment: "Formative" is one word I'd consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words that come to my mind are **nascent** and **infancy**.

```
nascent (adjective)
```

**definition**: just coming into existence and beginning to display signs of future potential.

*Usage:*

> The nascent stages of Andy's career proved to be challenging, yet he
>   came out with flying colors

```
infancy (noun)
```

**definition**: the early stage in the development or growth of something

*Usage:*

> The well established company has nurtured "Speak Up" culture right from its infancy.

I wanted to post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do that. So posting it as as answer.

**Edit:** : Edited answer, added definition and usage to be in line with the answer style guidelines of this community

Comment: "nascent" - that was it! You star! Big stack exchange point for you.

Answer (score 4):

It may have been ['seminal'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seminal?s=t)

> Seminal - **adjective**
>
> 4 - highly original and influencing the development of future events: 
>   a seminal artist; seminal ideas.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Or perhaps it was ['groundbreaking'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/groundbreaking?s=t)

> Groundbreaking - **adjective**
>
> 3 - originating or pioneering a new endeavor, field of inquiry, or the like: 
>   Pasteur's groundbreaking work in bacteriology.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Answer (score 1):

**Incipient**- something is in an early stage of existence. 
"In its incipient form, basketball was played with a soccer ball and peach baskets for goals. Bouncy orange balls and nets came later."